# How to do tx.addInput without tx_hash if sending from address for the first time?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, bitcoinjs

Iam using the bitcoinjs-lib library and trying to do a transaction. Iam doing the tx.addInput method before building but running into a build issue. I assume an error is thrown if blockchainScripthash_listunspent cannot retrieve the previous tx_hash.

Answer (score 1):

If not a coinbase transaction, you *have* to spend from an existing output. Thus the input *must* reference an existing transaction.

> cannot retrieve the previous tx_hash

Maybe the library you are using is the following common semantic:

- `txid` for the transaction id (hash *without* the witness data)
- `tx_hash` for the transaction hash (hash *with* the witness data)

You want the `txid` to reference a previous transaction in an input.